# Photoshop png background shows layered in iPhone simulator

Tags: uiimageview, interface-builder, background-image, photoshop

I created a gradient png in Photoshop CS6 which looks perfect on my windows box.
[I have mac as remote box so photo-editing is time-costly option on that box]

However as I put it on my development mac, I see so many layers unseen before.

It doesn't look pixelated, but it is not good for sure.
The image looks like Saturn Rings, with layers of gradient putting the beauty at stake.
It looks ugly.

It is sized 320X640, with 326 ppi.
I also made @2x (640X960) for ratina, but with same result.

[I also tried some of already available online backgrounds, but they all look same. Eventually, I want my own background as it has logo and everything placed as I wish]

What do I do?

(I have tried XCode IB View modes options (redraw, aspect fit etc. the whole list) already - and I am directly setting it in IB and from then on itself its ugly, so please do not ask how am I invoking it in XCode. Its equally ugly on mac Core Image Fun House software preview as well.)

Comment: I think this will be closed shortly because it's off-topic. Stackoverflow is for coding-related topics.

Comment: Not sure how they decide it, but this is very much XCode / mac specific. Possibly I am missing some file save settings in photoshop that I must adhere to for iPhone app design.

Comment: Sounds purely like a display issue. A cheaper monitor or something like that. You should post the image, but then again, this is really off-topic.